# what do i have to do to get my bot working again? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was rearranging the commands today to make the whole code look better and probably I did something wrong and the code stopped working, no error is displayed in the console, no informations about bot starts working. I will be grateful if someone helps. :)

```
import datetime
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
from discord.ext.commands import command, cooldown, BucketType

def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix) #prefix bota

client.remove_command('help') #usunięcie zbędnej komendy
status = cycle(['Serwer  ', 'IP: . ', 'Wersja ..+ ', '. - FineCone']) #Status bota
time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() #ustawienie czasu
client.run("there is a token but i deleted it in notepad :)") #token
wersja = "0.1.1" #wersja bota



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Status zaaktualizowany, Bonjour.') #Wiadomość Pokazuje się na konsoli gdy bot się załaduje

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '.'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

I haven't moved the rest of it, so it's definitely good

Comment: I really, really doubt you're gonna get any help at all, posting your whole project and waiting for someone to debug it for you is not the purpose of this site. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Always maintain your last working version of your code so that you can at least roll back any changes. Also, stating that something "doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Call out specifically what the expected behavior is and what is currently happening.

Answer (score 1):

Put `client.run("token")` at the **end** of your file, not at the top. Everything below it will never be executed.

```py
time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() #ustawienie czasu
# !! this is not supposed to be up here !!
client.run("there is a token but i deleted it in notepad :)") # token | remove this
wersja = "0.1.1" #wersja bota

@client.event
...
# .. events & commands

# instead put it on the LAST line
client.run("there is a token but i deleted it in notepad :)") # token
```